# Update record of Authentication system in laravel without Error message

Tags: laravel, authentication, request, record

I used Authentication system and want to update record of user is "logged in" and  use this code:

```
$data=User::find(Auth::user()->id);

//echo $date;
$data->gender=$request->gender;
$data->name=$request->username;
$data->mobile=$request->mobile;
$data->email=$request->email;
$data->address=$request->address;
$data->image=$request->image;
$data->save;
return redirect()->route('profile.view')->with('success',' User Updated successfuly');
```

but it doesn't update this record and doesn't receive an Error.

Comment: save is a method not an attribute use ```$data->save()```

Comment: Do you validate your input? It is not possible for it to show any errors unless you have somehow changed the way the errors are displayed. As query exception.

Comment: Also, you have no error management messages. Modify your code according to any possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.I dont use "()" end of save ! thanks